# Disable Incognito mode in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

Can I disable incognito mode in google chrome? We have Windows 8 home version. I was able to do it on an older computer, but can't find the answer for this newer version.

Comment: Hi, and wishing you a belated welcome to Super User! Why do you want to disable incognito mode?

Answer (score 2):

This answer to that question was found [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0VHa7diEVbQ)
I paste below the relevant one.

You will need to add an entry to the windows registry in order to disable it.

> simply add the following dword entry in the registry as this link describes
>   http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoModeAvailability
>
> Windows registry location:
>   Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\IncognitoModeAvailability
>
> Supported on: Google Chrome (Linux, Mac, Windows) since version 14
>   Google Chrome OS (Google Chrome OS) since version 0.14
>
> Description: Specifies whether the user may open pages in Incognito
>   mode in Google Chrome. If 'Enabled' is selected, pages may be opened
>   in Incognito mode. If 'Disabled' is selected, pages may not be opened
>   in Incognito mode. If 'Forced' is selected, pages may be opened ONLY
>   in Incognito mode. 
>   0 = Incognito mode available. 
>   1 = Incognito mode disabled. 
>   2 = Incognito mode forced.
>
> OR have this reg file do it for you
>   http://www.mediafire.com/file/dylcbs7aqpjc9vl/incognito diable.reg

I haven't tried it myself, as I don't have Windows 8. Although it seems that it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a software **IncognitoGone** and it is marvellous. It is a permanent removal of the private browsing system, and works well for Chrome and Internet Explorer. You can download it [here](http://download.cnet.com/Incognito-Gone/3000-2132_4-75651404.html).